# EF Core 3.1 Navigation property

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to connect the database tables with EF Core 3.1, based on the code below.
The problem is, that the ModellNavigation and the ManufacturerNavigation returns with null.
What am I doing wrong? Please help me with this.

```
        public IEnumerable<ViewModel> GetAll()
        {
            List<ViewModel> models = new List<ViewModel>();
            foreach(Detail detail in _context.Detail)
            {
                ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel
                {
                    ID = detail.DetailId,
                    Manufacturer = detail.ModellNavigation.ManufacturerNavigation.Name,
                    Modell = detail.ModellNavigation.Name,
                    Consumption = detail.Consumption,
                    Color = detail.Color,
                    Year = detail.Year,
                    Horsepower = detail.Horsepower
                };
                models.Add(viewModel);
            }
            return models;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show  your entity configuration for detail?

Comment: ```public partial class Detail
    {
        public int DetailId { get; set; }
        public decimal Consumption { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public DateTime Year { get; set; }
        public int Horsepower { get; set; }
        public int Modell { get; set; }

        public virtual Modell ModellNavigation { get; set; }
    }```

Comment: I think your configuration is lacking that is the reason why modelnavigation is null. Please check my answer.

Comment: Your relationship configuration may be correct but you would still need to enable lazy loading or explicitly load via `.Include`

Comment: Add that code to the question not as a comment

Comment: It still doesn't work unfortunatelly, can someone please maybe a show me a example about this lazy loading? Thank you in advance.

Comment: First fix your question, moving the code out of the comment and into the question, and explain what you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: Sorry but i'm new to this. It is quite hard for me to explain the exact issue.

Comment: I'm not asking to do that. I'm asking you to edit the question including the code that you posted as a comment because it's hard to read in the comment format and it is relevant to the question

Comment: Just posted the code, would you please check it? Thank you!

Comment: @PeterRuzsin he means to edit your question and add your code in the question. Can you Also show the context class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relationship of Detail and ModelNavigation in your EntityFramework Configuration so that it will load model navigation when accessing the detail model.
Please check this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: Sorry for that. The concept is the same. But I updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

In this code segment the modell returns with null although it uses the lasy loading!
Again, thanks for the help, I really appreciate it! (Please excuse my english, I'm not native!)

```
[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<CarView> getAllCars()
        {
            List<CarView> carViews = new List<CarView>();
            foreach(Manufacturer manufacturer in _context.Manufacturer)
            {
                CarView car = new CarView();
                car.Manufacturer = manufacturer.Name;
                foreach(Modell modell in manufacturer.Modell)
                {
                    car.Modell = modell.Name;
                    foreach(Detail detail in modell.Details)
                    {
                        car.ID = detail.DetailId;
                        car.Consumption = detail.Consumption;
                        car.Color = detail.Color;
                        car.Year = detail.Year;
                        car.Horsepower = detail.Horsepower;
                    }
                }
                carViews.Add(car);
            }
            return carViews;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerating like you do will make one query per loop, and if you also add lazy loading it will generate even more queries and complexity.

You should project your query directly in EF Core instead, which will generate only one query to the database.

```
public IEnumerable<ViewModel> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Detail.Select(
        d => new ViewModel()
        {
            ID = detail.DetailId,
            Manufacturer = detail.ModellNavigation.ManufacturerNavigation.Name,
            Modell = detail.ModellNavigation.Name,
            Consumption = detail.Consumption,
            Color = detail.Color,
            Year = detail.Year,
            Horsepower = detail.Horsepower
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```